# Why does $1+2+\dots+2003=\dfrac{2004\cdot2003}2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Why does $1+2+\dots+2003=\dfrac{2004\cdot2003}2$?

Sorry if this is missing context; not really much to add...

Comment: have you heard arithmetic progression? 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: Because half a square is a triangle.

Comment: @Evariste what?

Comment: @Evariste isn't it a rectangle?

Comment: I realize I was a bit quick, but essentially the idea is a square. As you can see, $2003\times 2004$ is very close to a square. This pictures helps the understanding a bit :http://oi67.tinypic.com/e9vvi8.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
S&=&1&+&2&+&3&+&\ldots&+&2001&+&2002&+&2003\\
S&=&2003&+&2002&+&2001&+&\ldots&+&3&+&2&+&1\\ \hline
2S&=&2004&+&2004&+&2004&+&\ldots&+&2004&+&2004&+&2004
\end{array}$$

There are $2003$ columns, so $2S=2003\cdot2004$, and therefore $S=\dfrac{2003\cdot2004}2$.

Comment: This formatting is gorgeous; great use of array.

Comment: @suomynonA: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 3):

By symmetry, the numbers are all centered around $\frac{n+1}{2}$, and there are $n$ of them.

Comment: Yeah, the number $\frac{n+1}{2}$ is an axis of symmetry for the numbers, when you look at them on the number line.

Comment: This kind of answer is only useful to those who are used to phrases like "by symmetry"

Comment: well. I tried to answer the question "why" as much as possible.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

You can show by induction.